# How to get a windowless application in Ogre?

Tags: windows, window, ogre3d, ogre

I'm trying to create a windowless Ogre application, but it seems that the method RenderWindow::setVisible(false) is completely ignored by the application. Is there a way to accomplish that?

Thank you
Tommaso

Comment: Having never used ogre I would assume that `setVisible(true)` would mean **show** the window?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should not be using `RenderWindow` but [`RenderTexture`](http://www.ogre3d.org/docs/api/html/classOgre_1_1RenderTexture.html) if you don't want to open a window. It works almost exactly the same as `RenderWindow` because it is derived from `RenderTarget` as well. You should have almost no trouble just switching them around with your current parameters except for changing the constructor.

Please update your question with some concrete code if you *do* run into trouble with the switch.

Comment: So it's supposed to have a working RenderTexture without a RenderWindow? I've a weird problem with RenderTexture: [RenderTexture bigger than RenderWindow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7930306/ogre-3d-rendertexture-bigger-than-renderwindow)

Comment: But RenderTexture is an abstract class in 1.9?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you **have** to create a window even if you just want create a windowless app. It is not possible to initialize Ogre without creating a RenderWindow (`window = m_root->initialise(true, "App")`)
With Ogre 1.8 you can hide the window by calling `window->setHidden(true)` 
Thanks to this method you can bypass the problem and make a "windowless" app.

As Svenstaro said, you can redirect the rendering into a RenderTexture. I use the code below to render my frames into a texture :

```
m_window = m_root->initialise(true, "App");
m_window->setHidden(true);
Ogre::WindowEventUtilities::messagePump(); // Force the window to be hidden (necessary under Ubuntu for my case)

m_camera = m_sceneMgr->createCamera("Cam");

Ogre::TexturePtr rtt_texture = Ogre::TextureManager::getSingleton().createManual("RttTex",
                Ogre::ResourceGroupManager::DEFAULT_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME,
                Ogre::TEX_TYPE_2D, 640, 480, 0,
                Ogre::PF_R8G8B8,
                Ogre::TU_RENDERTARGET);

Ogre::RenderTexture* m_tex = rtt_texture->getBuffer()->getRenderTarget();
Ogre::Viewport* vp = m_tex->addViewport(m_camera);
vp->setClearEveryFrame(true);
vp->setBackgroundColour(Ogre::ColourValue::Black);
vp->setOverlaysEnabled(false);
m_camera->setAspectRatio(Ogre::Real(vp->getActualWidth()) / Ogre::Real(vp->getActualHeight()));
```

In the RenderLoop :

```
while(1)
{
  m_root->renderOneFrame();
  m_tex->update();

  // Other stuffs
}
```