# How to get a windowless application in Ogre using ApplicationContextBase

Tags: windows, window, ogre, ogre3d

I've already tried using `window->setHidden(true)`, but that doesn't take any effect.

There is a similar post which shows' how to do that ([How to get a windowless application in Ogre?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397160/how-to-get-a-windowless-application-in-ogre)), but I've already tried its solution and it didn't worked out. I think
it's because they were not implementing [ApplicationContextBase][1], which I prefer for my project.